# Express.js - Load database reference before routing

Tags: mongodb, express

Currently, i have to wrap my express routes in a mongoDb connect call, in order to pass a database reference to the corresponding function:

```
mongoClient.connect(mongourl,function(err,database){

    if (err){
        throw err;
    }

    database = database.db('quac');

    app.get('/', routes.index(database));

    app.post('/add/:title', routes.add(database));

});
```

I would like to avoid this wrap and rather load the database reference in first place.

What would be the best practice to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are set on passing the reference or just want to access mongoose in your controllers. For the later then there is no need to pass your db ref - just require mongoose and it will detect a current connection.

So in your app.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect Mongo database
mongoose.connect(config.db.mongo.connection, config.db.mongo.options);

// Require your models
require("../models/something");
require("../models/other");
```

Then in your controller:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Something = mongoose.model('Something'),
  Other = mongoose.model('Other');

...
Other.findById(...)
```

If for some reason you need the connection itself it is available as:

```
mongoose.connections[0]
```